# Close window automatically after printing dialog closes in javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

The scenario is this: you are in a window (A), where you click a button/link to launch the printing process, then a new window (B) with the contents to be printed is opened, the printing dialogue is shown immediately, if you click cancel button of windows (B) then you should again able to print but when you once click ,print button of window ( B) to print then you can able to print but button of windows ( A) cannot be again proceed to print again.
Give me some solution..!!!which works on chrome ,Firefox and internet explorer

Comment: "Give me solution", no you give us some code and a problem and we can help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, what have you tried till now to accomplish the above tasks ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your scenario would be to assign a variable to your new window function. Then you can communicate with that new window from the newly assigned variable.

Access the document object of Window B from Window A with

```
assignedVariable.document
```